# Excel VBA CreateObject: Run-time error '432': File name or class not found during Automation operation

Tags: vba, excel, dll, createobject

How do I fix the error "Run-time error '432': File name or class not found during Automation operation" I get when calling "CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")" in Excel VBA?

I have a spreadsheet with a macro that works on two other computers and used to work on my computer before I factory restored it and reinstalled Office.

I am on Windows 7 64-bit, running Office Home and Student 2010.

I traced the error down and created a new spreadsheet with a macro that runs a single line:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

This macro runs fine on 2 other computers, so there's something in my PC environment that's screwing me up. I get the error:

> Run-time error '432': File name or class name not found during
>   Automation operation

I've tried repairing the Office installation and completely uninstalling and reinstalling Office.

From what I can find on the internet, I might need a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime". I believe this is the file scrrun.dll.
When I go to add this reference to my project, it shows me that the location of "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" is "C:\Users\\Documents". You can see this in the attached image full of errors.
That doesn't seem like the correct location, and there are no dlls there.

If I check that reference to include it and hit OK, I get the error:

> Error in loading DLL

scrrun.dll is found in "C:\Windows\System32"
I tried registering the dll and it worked fine. Unregistering gives me the error:

> The module "scrrun.dll was loaded but the call to DLLUnregisterServer
>   failed with error code 0x800300002.

I made sure the Administrators group owns that file in case it was a permissions issue. I also tried unregistering while running in Safe Mode.

I may be off on a total tangent looking at the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference and/or scrrun.dll.

Thanks for any advice!

[image: Screenshots of various errors]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

The question is:
How do I fix the error "Run-time error '432': File name or class not found during Automation operation" I get when calling "CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")" in Excel VBA?

Comment: I did not go through your question, but I am 90% sure you need to clean your registry. Similar things have happened to me and this happens when you install any newer version, or older version of any microsoft products that can insert another registry setting, which confuses the automation. Google the exact error code and look for answers that show you how to go to the registry and delete one of the elements. make sure you google the error number and description.

Comment: What MS Office version do you have? 32 or 64 bit? Try to work with "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll"

Comment: @omegastripes The office disk has 32 and 64 bit install folders. I'm going to remove it and try explicitly running from the 64 bit directory.

But I had this same version of Office installed before I factory restored my PC and this code was working.

Comment: @omegastripes After installing directly from the x64 directory on the Office disk, I can run the code without errors.

Thank you to everyone for your help with this.

Comment: A few weeks later, I started having a very similar problem, this time with the line of code:

`CreateObject("CDO.message")`

This time I was able to fix it by un-registering and re-registering cdosys.dll in the System32 and SysWOW64 directories.

Answer (score 0):

It works with me as below. Hope it helps
- I find scrrun.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64. I register it in this location successfully
- Recheck in VBA Reference, it shows location of Microsoft Scripting Runtime as C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll

Then i have no below error anymore
   "Run-time error '432': File name or class not found during Automation operation" I get when calling "CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")" in Excel VBA"